# ibmiotf client doesn't publish when using mqtt.js simultaneously

Tags: node.js, mqtt, watson-iot

I am working on a project with multiple brokers, the first one is IBM IoT Watson, and the second one is my broker.

I am trying to connect to both of them, listen to changes to my broker, and publishing them to IBM Watson IOT.

I am using nodejs ibmiotf and mqtt.js,

here's the code:

```
const mqtt = require('mqtt');
const Client = require("ibmiotf");
const appClientConfig = require('../config').watsonIoTConfigs;
const rp = require('request-promise');
let appClient = new Client.IotfApplication(appClientConfig);
appClient.connect();

let myClient  = new mqtt.connect('tcp://myserver', {
    clientId: 'id222s2',
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password',
    port: 221112,
    will: {
        topic: 'server_disconnected',
        payload: "Server disconnected!, please call technical support",
        qos: 2
    }
});

appClient.on("connect", () => {
    console.log('ibmiot connected');
    appClient.subscribeToDeviceStatus();
    appClient.subscribeToDeviceEvents();
});

myClient.on('message', function (topic, message) {
  appClient.publish("topic1", "json", 'something') // here the ibmiotf disconnect
}
```

then I got this error once it tries to publish :

```
[BaseClient:connect] Iotfclient is offline. Retrying connection
```

And after that, it never connect and gives me :

```
Error : [ApplicationClient:publish] Client is not connected
```

what is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your Watson IoT Platform client is unable to connect - typically this happens if you've misconfigured the config file (e.g., an incorrect API key/token). Are you happy to share the config file - just obfuscate any passwords/tokens - and we can look for obvious issues with it.

Comment: Yes, sure, here's the configurations:

watsonIoTConfigs:{
        "org" : '22a32',
        "id" : 'myBackendApp-test',
        "auth-key" : '*********************',
        "auth-token" : '*******************'
    }

Comment: But, actually, it connects if i removed the other mqtt connections. so it works when it's only alone!

Comment: actually, only by remove the publish line, it works well!

Comment: seems like I am unable to publish, event I am not connected to my mqtt!

Comment: how does the publish line looks like? It might be doing smth wrong and probably that is the reason why you get disconnected

Comment: "22a32" doesn't look like a valid orgId to me; I'd expect it to have 6 characters?